# gmaps4rails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I encountered the following error when I submit an empty address (street + city ) field.

```
undefined method `nom_ville' for nil:NilClass

app/models/venue.rb:15:in `gmaps4rails_address'
app/controllers/venues_controller.rb:74:in `block in create'
app/controllers/venues_controller.rb:73:in `create'
```

My Model

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :type
  belongs_to :ville
  belongs_to :departement
  belongs_to :region
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games

  acts_as_gmappable

  validates :rue, :nom, :ville_id, :region_id, :departement_id, :presence => true

  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{self.rue}, #{self.ville.nom_ville}, France"
  end
end
```

`nom_ville` is coming from the `Ville model`, but the object `Venue` have not been created because validation fails (`:rue`, `:nom` are empty).

Why `gmaps4rails` add not errors on the `Venue` model ?

Sorry for my english,
Thanks,

Nelson

Comment: It's not about gmaps4rails I think. Basically, you just created a venue, did not set the `ville`, so in `gmaps4rails_address`, you're trying to access nom_ville on a nil object. You just need a test in this method to avoid this, and then the basic rails validation will kick in since rue and ville are required.

Comment: @Robin is right. Nothing to add

Comment: Ok, cool if you agree. I'll just post this as the answer then.

Comment: Finally you are right ! Sorry for thé delay ...

Answer (score 2):

It's not about gmaps4rails I think. Basically, you just created a venue, did not set the ville, so in `gmaps4rails_address`, you're trying to access `nom_ville` on a `nil` object. You just need a test in this method to avoid this, and then the basic rails validation will kick in since rue and ville are required.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def gmaps4rails_address
  if self.ville
    "#{self.rue}, #{self.ville.nom_ville}, France"
  else
    <do something else>
  end
end
```

Comment: didn't realize how old this question was, my bad